# How to generate a PDF file using PHP or Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, pdf, fpdf

I need to generate a pdf file by adding pages from an already generated pdf using only php or javascript.
I tried fpdf but could not find any appropriate function. Is there a method I could use to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an extension that should allow this to work called [FPDI](http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi/)

That being said, I've not had a ton of luck through the years using FPDF.  I've always fallen back to DomPDF or the likes.  Like anything Adobe touches, PDF is not the most friendly tool in the world for those of us charged to make them work.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:
http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi/